# Как передать ArrayList с Activity в Fragment используя Parcelable?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Как перадать ArrayList с Activity в Fragment используя интерфейс Parcelable
и извлечь данные в Fragment ?

Activity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    ArrayList<Parcelable> parcelableArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ArrayList carList = new ArrayList();
          carList.add(new Car(1, "Honda", "Black"));
          carList.add(new Car(2, "Toyota", "Blue"));
          carList.add(new Car(3, "Suzuki", "Green"));


        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("name",carList);


        Fragment fragobj=new MyFragment();
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fmContent, fragobj)
                .commit();
    }
```

Fragment.class

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{


    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    Bundle bundle;

    TextView text;
    TextView article;

    ArrayList<String > arrayList = new ArrayList<String >();
    ArrayList<Parcelable> parcelableArrayList;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        parcelableArrayList = getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("name");
        if (parcelableArrayList  !=null){

            Log.d(LOG_TAG,  " ------------------------->  myBundle contain IS "+arrayList.get(1));
        }else {
            final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
           // Bundle bundle;
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,  " ------------------------->  myBundle contain IS "+"NULL");
        }

        return view;

    }

}
```

В классе MyFragment.java получаю  null на строке parcelableArrayList = getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("Student");

Как правильно организовать код для передачи типа ArrayList?

Answer (score 1):

Тут

> parcelableArrayList = getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("name");

вы пытаетесь получить данные из интента актвити, а вам надо из аргументов фрагмента. Т.е. так:

```
parcelableArrayList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("name");
```

Comment: В методе getArguments()   нету этого метода для Fragment   -   Error:(67, 45) error: cannot find symbol method getParcelableArrayListExtra(String)

Comment: @mtb, тут лишнее слово Extra. Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

1.Сделайте ArrayList - приватным полем в вашей Активности.

2.Создайте следующий метод в активности:

```
piblic ArrayList getArrayList(){
return MyArrayList
}
```

3.В фрагменте сделайте следующее:

```
ArrayList<YourGeneric> MyNewArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
MyNewArrayList = MainActivity.getArrayList();
```

Comment: Ваш код не скомпилируется, т.к. не найдёт в MainActivity такого метода, т.к. он не статический, а вы пытаетесь статический вызвать. Да и в любом случае так делать не надо.

Comment: На удивление работает)

Comment: Видимо выше у вас объявлена переменная MainActivity. Если так - то соблюдайте конвенции именования переменнных - ваш код в нынешнем виде читается не так как исполняется. Переменные нужно именовать с маленькой буквы